# Nvcc missing when installing cudatoolkit?

Tags: cuda, anaconda, pytorch, nvcc

I have installed cuda along pytorch with

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

However, it seems like nvcc was not installed along with it. If I want to use for example `nvcc -V`, I get the error that nvcc was not found, and that I should install it with `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit.` 
Can I do this (I dont want to just try and then find out that it is not working/messes up the whole cuda setup).
And is this a bug or expected behavior?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and have cuda 10.2

Comment: The `cudatoolkit` installed using `conda install` is not the same as the CUDA toolkit packaged up by NVIDIA. It is a subset, to provide the needed components for other packages installed by `conda` such as `pytorch`.  It's likely that it is all you need if you only need to use pytorch.  If you need/want the full CUDA toolkit for some other reason, you can install it using a variety of methods including some variant of the one you indicate, but it will install a separate copy, in another location from what is typically used by conda packages.  This all looks like expected behavior to me.

Comment: NVIDIA publishes a [CUDA linux install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) which may be useful.  It doesn't have conda packages or methods in view, however.

Comment: You haven't mentioned if you have a GPU, or what GPU you have, or if you installed a GPU driver, or what GPU driver you installed, but that is all important.  The simplest instruction for compatibility is to install the latest driver for your GPU, if you've not already done so.  Installing a CUDA toolkit from NVIDIA may install a proper/sufficient driver for you, depending on what exactly you install.  Generally, `conda install ...` does not install a GPU driver, in my experience.

Comment: An Faster-RCNN implementation I want to use needs nvcc. I do have a gpu, and Pytorch runs flawless otherwise. So the safest bet is to uninistall the conda cudatoolkit and install cuda manually? Do you know of any good installlation script that automates the installation?

Comment: I think you will discover that it is harder to get your conda install of pytorch to use a CUDA toolkit other than the one installed by conda.   I don't know what the safest bet is; I regularly use a machine that has the cuda toolkit installed by conda and a separate install that I did using the instructions I already provided.  
 That may or may not work for your use case.  Versions do matter.  Requests for tutorials, scripts, off-site resources are generally off-topic for stack overflow, from what I have seen.

Answer (score 32):

Met this question when installing `cudatoolkit` of 10.1 with PyTorch 1.4.

There is a `conda-forge` package `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cudatoolkit-dev`. After installing this, `nvcc` as well as other CUDA libraries will be then available at `/home/li/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/pkgs/cuda-toolkit` in `bin/` and `lib/`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it currently has 10.1 and I need 10.2

Comment: @tejasvi88 try requesting this by https://github.com/conda-forge/cudatoolkit-dev-feedstock

Comment: Strange why it doesn't have version 10.2 :/

Comment: Gets stuck on "Executing transaction" and then eventually fails :/

Answer (score 16):

nvidia conda channel is now available: [nvidia/cuda](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#conda-installation) and [nvcc](https://anaconda.org/nvidia/repo) is in it:

```
conda install cuda -c nvidia
```

Comment: Don't think this has 10.2.

Comment: @john I am afraid not.

Comment: I was specifically looking for version 10.2 too. But then I realized that I can safely upgrade to 11.3 (some old project on PyTorch 1.6.0)

Answer (score 13):

`cudatoolkit` that is installed with pytorch is runtime only and does not come with the development compiler `nvcc`. To get `nvcc` you need to install `cudatoolkit-dev` which I believe is available from the `conda-forge` channel.

Comment: From the Nvidia website ( [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) ), I see that CUDA packages can be installed selectively. Is it sufficient to only install nvcc?

Comment: I haven't tried with selective install but seems okay since the nvcc installation will check for any dependencies beforehand

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
conda install -c conda-forge nvcc_linux-64
```

Currently this should get you 10.2. Nvidia has its own channel nvidia but the latest version there is 10.1.

Comment: Followed this answer but found out that this seems not solving the problems. The nvcc installed by `nvcc_linux-64` is merely a shell script calling `$(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc`

Comment: as it say in the description of the [package](https://anaconda.org/search?q=nvcc): "A meta-package to enable the right nvcc." not really nvcc

Comment: People, listen to the guys above my comment: this does NOT install nvcc! It is like a shortcut to nowhere! You will waste time figuring out what is wrong when you don't have nvcc in the first place!

Comment: This answer is on a good track, I read an article stating the most "robust" way to get NVCC is to install Cuda on host and use conda nvcc_linux-64 to basically make your Env aware of the local installation. See https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-conda-environment-for-horovod-773bd036bf64

Answer (score 5):

`cudatoolkit-dev` package from `conda-forge` did not work for me. I used the package from `HCC` with the latest pytorch (v1.9.0) https://anaconda.org/HCC/cudatoolkit.

The command to install `cudatoolkit` alongside `pytorch` and `torchvision`:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch -c hcc
```

After the installation, you can check

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

Comment: Looks like this is also only for Linux

Comment: @Sterling I haven't tested the commands on a Windows machine. So, probably it is only for Linux.

Comment: Just checked `cudatoolkit` package on HCC repo. HCC provides `cudatoolkit` package only for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Check if nvcc is in the folder `/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin`
Run `./nvcc --version` if it exists in that folder

Output looks like this

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

If this is the case, add the folder to your global path variable
`echo "export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}" >> ~/.profile`

and refresh the profile using
`source ~/.profile`

and reboot your machine.