# Why in anaconda installing cudnn 7.6.5 when the supported version for TF 2.0 (with GPU) is 7.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59529804)

I have installed TensorFlow (GPU) with anaconda using the installation instructions in [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

But I realized Anaconda is installing library cudnn version 7.6.5

According to [TensorFlow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)
it should not be installing cudnn 7.4?

This can cause any problem?

Comment: "...the supported version for TF 2.0 ( with GPU ) is 7.4" -> Where did you find this? [official TF guide says >= 7.6](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements). The page you link shows only the **tested** build configurations, it doesn't mean you must stick to those. CuDNN 7.6 has been in use for quite a long time now

Comment: Anaconda does their own build of TensorFlow, they can use whatever version of CUDA and cudnn they want. They have been building with cudnn 7.6 for the last 7 months: https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/tensorflow_recipes/blame/master/tensorflow-base-gpu/conda_build_config.yaml#L16

Comment: @GPhilo@William D.Irons   Thank for your comments, have been of big help !