# CUDA 11.1 Torch 3.8 + Conda issues trying to build Apex. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, ubuntu-20.04

I started from a clean environment (I think), and I removed cuda and nvidia related drivers. From a fresh conda envrionment, I did the following:

```
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

Following this, I installed nvidia-driver-450 with apt and restarted my computer. `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns true, however, when I try to build apex I get the following issue:

```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Supposedly this occurs when you try to build the repo without GPU, which I don't understand why that would be.

Side question: I cant figure this out. I deleted cuda from /usr/local because I kept having issues, and for the most part, using the cudatoolkit install by conda seems to work fine. Do I need to apt install cuda? I would really like to not, if possible.

I attempted multiple times to install the relevant drivers and wound up restarting from scratch as described above. I also tried setting TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST to "compute capability", but this did not work.

EDIT:
Figured it out. conda install cudatoolkit does NOT give you all cuda binarys. After doing that install, you have to set CUDA_HOME to CONDA_PREFIX, however, nvcc wont be in the Conda bin. So I need to install a development version like here: ibm.com/docs/en/wmlce/…. I'll just keep this open for future people

Comment: https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/990

Comment: @talonmies I updated my post just now, but that is one of the attempts I made. I scoured the internet for this one and tried just about everything. For some reason, python build commands think I have no cuda_runtime when it finds it way to making binaries, and I'm also encountering this issue elsewhere:   `/cuda/CUDAContext.h:5:10: fatal error: cuda_runtime_api.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <cuda_runtime_api.h>`. This issue is almost definitely happening because I have no cuda in /usr/local, but I installed it with conda, wherever that is.

Comment: I just answered my own question somewhat above and figured it out. conda install cudatoolkit does NOT give you all cuda binarys. After doing that install, you have to set CUDA_HOME to CONDA_PREFIX, however, nvcc wont be in the Conda bin. So I need to install a development version like here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wmlce/1.6.0?topic=frameworks-building-packages-applications-interface-powerai. I'll just keep this open for future people

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvcc missing when installing cudatoolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470424/nvcc-missing-when-installing-cudatoolkit)